# XAMPP (Apache) Crashes after adding mongodb.so to php.ini

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, laravel, xampp

I'm trying to use MongoDB with Laravel for the first time with XAMPP (OSX) and the Jenssegers/mongodb plugin:
- https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I have added the following line to the php.ini file.
extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-mongodb/mongodb.so"

**Afterwards apache is unable to run.**

error log shows the following:

---

[Sun Apr 16 19:55:16.004447 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 64283] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sun Apr 16 19:55:16.004729 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 64283] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Apr 16 19:55:17.002106 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 64284] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sun Apr 16 19:55:17.002248 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 64284] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

---

This question has been asked a couple of time:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/247

Using the --with-mongodb-sasl=no argument might solve it?
As a total newbie, I have no clue how to use this though..
Can anyone help me with this problem??

php version: 5.6.3
mongodb version: 1.2.8
Laravel version: 5.4
Jenssegers/mongodb extension version: 3.2

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
$ cd mongo-php-driver
$ git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-mongodb-sasl=no
$ make all -j 5
$ sudo make install
```

Then copy/paste **mongodb.so** to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212`
and then restart Apache

this steps are working on macos el-capitan